# Can Github be used for Web Development?

Tags: html, github

I'm a Web Dev. and I'm very new to Github and I was wondering if Github can be used for Web Development. If it can't then what lang. are commonly used for Github?

Comment: This seems a bit unclear, but seems to me it's not within the guidelines. Please confirm you're asking the correct question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: This is not a proper way to find out what is `Github`. you can search about it and investigate, asking question like this is not proper way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github is a plattform for hosting git-repository.

It is not about programming language but about storing versions of your code an collaborating.

Basically you can use Github or any other git hosting for basically every programming project.

Here an article why it is a good idea to use git as a version control: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/git-version-control-youre-developer/

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: I appreciate I was able to help you

Answer (score 2):

Github lets you host you your code. Collaborate with people writing your code, showing it to the world, manage the version of your code. What is basically hosts is a git repository. Take a look over [here](https://www.coredna.com/blogs/what-is-git-and-github-part-two) to get an idea. One interesting thing, GitHub provides is letting you host static websites. It also provides the free domain name like `yourUserNme.github.io`. [This](https://gist.github.com/TylerFisher/6127328) tells how to do it. You can also use jykll template to host your site on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

you can git every lang , such as php ,html ,css and etc..

Answer (score 0):

GitHub is a web-based hosting service for version control using Git. It is mostly used for computer code. It offers all of the distributed version control and source code management (SCM) functionality of Git as well as adding its own features. It provides access control and several collaboration features such as bug tracking, feature requests, task management, and wikis for every project.
It is not the programming language. I guess you can store most of your code in GitHub, and which can be used for version control. you can easily learn it from the following online tutorial link. https://lab.github.com/